# how to upload kmm module to git repo?

Tags: kmm

I am using KMM (Android, IOS)
this is a working fine, the kmm generates the podspec, and Xcode consumes it from the pod profile

```
#pod 'shared', :path => '../app-android/shared
```

however, I want such a way to share the kmm module on the git repo so the IOS team can use it without cloning the android project,KMM if possible (just shared binary)

I saw `"com.chromaticnoise.multiplatform-swiftpackage"` , but this is an old library and not update for 16 month

is there any way to access the shared pod on git repo and costume from Xcode?

Comment: search for "kmm fat framework", there are a couple of articles describing how to setup gradle task, which will create a file that you can push

Comment: This “Fat” framework method no longer works with XCode 12+. Use an XCFramework instead.